# Capture contents in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text:

```
text = itunes20140618.tbz
```

How would I capture the date here, using a regular expression?

I am currently doing:

```
date = text.split('.tbz')[0].split('itunes')[-1]
```

I think using a `re.findall` here would be cleaner for what I am trying to do. Please note in the regular expression, it needs to be after the specific word "itunes" for the capture group (not just not numbers).

Comment: Try `(\d+)\.` and get matched group at index 1 that returns `20140618`. Here is [DEMO](https://www.debuggex.com/r/azv9cwzfpOz-5hBe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) to find your desired match.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'\d+', 'itunes20140618.tbz').group()
'20140618'
```

Since you state it has to be after the word *itunes*, you can use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and refer to that group number to access your match.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'itunes(\d+)', 'itunes20140618.tbz').group(1)
'20140618'
```

You can also use a **[Positive Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)** to assure it's after the word *itunes*.

```
>>> re.search(r'(?<=itunes)\d+', 'itunes20140618.tbz').group()
'20140618'
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
[^\d]*(\d+).*
```

[**Live demo**](http://regex101.com/r/jA8lM0)

If you guarantee that the expression is going to be of this form:
`itunes` followed by `date`, then you can also use this:

```
itunes(\d+).*
```